# How to override the default activiti spring-boot configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, activiti

I'm working on a Spring Boot application and trying to tweak my Activiti process engine settings. I have added the Activiti dependency to my `pom.xml` and Boot is able to start and load my `BPMN` files correctly.

What I would like to do now is to override some of the Spring Boot defaults, for example `MailServerHost` setting. Is there a way to do that in the `application.properties` file? I looked around but can't find a reference that lists those properties. I guess I'm looking for something like [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html]) for the Activiti properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using the Spring Boot Starter for Activiti? Then you can configure the specific properties in your application.properties or .yml, for example:

```
spring.activiti.mailServerHost=
spring.activiti.mailServerPort=
spring.activiti.mailServerDefaultFrom=
```

You can see the whole list of available properties in the class `org.activiti.spring.boot.ActivitiProperties` (see the [Github repository](https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/blob/master/modules/activiti-spring-boot/spring-boot-starters/activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic/src/main/java/org/activiti/spring/boot/ActivitiProperties.java)). The prefix is always `spring.activiti` plus the name of the variable. You also see the default values there.

Activiti doesn't use the default Spring Mail configuration, so the `spring.mail.` properties won't have any effect.

If you use IntelliJ or Eclipse with activated Spring Boot integrations, you should get some autocompletion for that properties, when you edit your configuration file.

Comment: Thanks dunni, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can override it in application.properties file . See [Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) here

see email section. Here is the relevant section

```
# Email (MailProperties)
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8 # Default MimeMessage encoding.
spring.mail.host= # SMTP server host. For instance `smtp.example.com`
spring.mail.jndi-name= # Session JNDI name. When set, takes precedence to others mail settings.
spring.mail.password= # Login password of the SMTP server.
spring.mail.port= # SMTP server port.
spring.mail.properties.*= # Additional JavaMail session properties.
spring.mail.protocol=smtp # Protocol used by the SMTP server.
spring.mail.test-connection=false # Test that the mail server is available on startup.
spring.mail.username= # Login user of the SMTP server.
```

Comment: Thanks M Sach, am looking for the Activiti specific configurations, as in dunni's answer.